# Django form.MultipleChoiceField . Customize checkboxes in template

Tags: django, forms

I have this form:

```
class PasswordForm(forms.Form):

    CHOICES=[('uppercase','Uppercase'),
            ('lowercase','Lowercase'),
            ('numbers','Numbers'),]

    password_length = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)],)
    options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=CHOICES,)
```

How can I customize in template my checkbox fields?
I know how I can do it with other fields, like `forms.Charfield()` or my `password_length`, just

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{form.some_field}}
</form>
```

but it doent works with my `MultipleChoiceField`, I tried many things like
`{{form.uppercase}}`, `{{form.options.choices.uppercase}}` and tried `{% for %}` loop.
it just return nothing, and I dont see it in html via browser inspector.

Comment: What does *doent works* entail? errors? invalid results? What is it you're trying to do that isn't currently happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write these options as fields of the form:

```
class PasswordForm(forms.Form):
    uppercase = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    lowercase = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    numbers = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    password_length = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)],)
```

and then render the form to template, and in template:

```
{{ form.uppercase }}
```

will show

```
<input name="uppercase" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
 <!-- With for-cycle: -->
{% for field in form %}
  {% for choice_id, choice_label in field.field.choices %}
    {{choice_id}}
    {{choice_label}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- And my end version, where I edited only certain field. -->
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.name == "your-field-name-here"%}
       <p><strong>{{field.name}}: </strong></p>
       {% for choice_id, choice_label in field.field.choices %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="{{choice_id}}" style="display:inline;">{{choice_label}}
      {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
       <p>{{ field.errors }}<label style="display:table-cell;">{{field.name}}: </label>{{ field }}</p>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- If you want to edit all fields with options: {% if field.choices %} -->
```